# Teradata current_timestamp in CST is shown as GMT

Tags: teradata

```
select current_timestamp(0) ;

Current TimeStamp(0)
2021-08-30 17:29:30+00:00
```

Actual CDT time now - 2021-08-30 17:29:30, but timezone is shown as GMT(+00:00) instead of CDT(-05:00). How can this be fixed.

Comment: It's complicated. You would need to set [TimeDateWZControl](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Mj_BZM0LvaG1EFWo7wQ~4A/UzVD0J4CSynhKCk31kAukA)  in `dbscontrol` along with configuring `tdlocaledef` settings (if you need daylight saving adjustment) or SystemTimeZoneHour / SystemTimeZoneMinute. But there are nuances in terms of which option would be best and what might need to be done with data already loaded. Might want to get help from the Teradata.

Comment: Is there a way any function that can fix timezone. "AT TIME ZONE" gives wrong result and shows time in CST time as GMT. Looking for temporary solution that can fix query resultset.

Comment: If you just want the appearance of -05:00 you can add and subtract the same offset, like this `(myTimestamp + INTERVAL '5' HOUR) AT 'GMT-5'`, but if you need daylight savings adjustment for CST/CDT (`AT 'America Central'` can be either -6 or -5 hours) then it will be harder.